# Having trouble tracking cartID as session and int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, oop, shopping-cart

I'm customizing the MVC music store to fit my needs in MVC3. The one hang up I am having is where they track the CartID as a string of the user's username, I want to track it via the userID, instead as we won't have usernames. Anyway, I'm having problems with this function:

```
 public int GetCartId(HttpContextBase context)
 {
        if (context.Session[CartSessionKey] == null)
        {
            if (context.Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                context.Session[CartSessionKey] = context.Session["UserID"];
            }
            else
            {
                //Generate a new random GUID using System.Guid class
                Guid tempCartId = Guid.NewGuid();
                //Send tempCartId back to client as a cookie
                context.Session[CartSessionKey] = tempCartId;
            }
        }

 return context.Session[CartSessionKey];

 }
```

Where I am getting the error of

> "Error   20  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I understand that `context.Session[CartSessionKey]` is an object and not an int, but I don't know the best way to :

A) Convert all this stuff to use Ints instead of GUID's and sessions, or

B) If this is a bad way to do this, how can I improve my code to more appropriately assign a random int for a cartID if the user is not logged in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to cast the object as int if you're storing an int into the Session object instead of a GUID.

int x = (int)context.Session[CartSessionKey]